# importing javascript library once

Tags: javascript, html, browser, web, browser-cache

I'm building a website which imports a javascript library (located inside `<head>`):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("nicedit/nicEdit.js")"></script>
```

which means,
every page loading (no matter which page in my website), this line exists.

I wanted to know if modern browsers download the library once, and then cache it,
or every page load - the javascript is library re-downloaded.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under normal circumstances most browsers will cache a javascript file if it is repeatedly requested from the same url; however, my definition of *normal circumstances* is wrapped up in how servers are usually set up. The real result depends on what [cache headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html) the server is sending, as well as whether or not the URL changes (which is not clear from your question).

There are lots of questions on StackOverflow about caching JavaScript. [This one includes something of a compendium.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311062/caching-javascript-files)

Comment: I'm using play framework (java based web framework). I need to find out if I can control the cache headers (I think it is possible)

Answer (score 1):

Please try configuring http.cacheControl

> http.cacheControl
>
> HTTP Response headers control for static files: sets the default
>   max-age in seconds, telling the user’s browser how long it should
>   cache the page. This is only read in prod mode, in dev mode the cache
>   is disabled. For example, to send no-cache:
>
> http.cacheControl=0 Default: 3600 - set cache expiry to one hour.

[Source](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/configuration) of the information.