# Concatenating raw javascript to a webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm currently working on a build process that uses webpack. One of the dependencies that I need to include in my bundle is an old third-party library that doesn't follow any module patterns. I wan't to just include it in it's raw form, but it's coded in such a way that the usual techniques don't work.

The offending library is coded a bit like this:

```
function OldLibrary() {
  console.log('What are modules?');
};
var foo = window.OldLibrary;
// Proceeds to use foo without a care in the world
```

As you can see from the code above, the library assumes that it will always be in the global context, and so it doesn't bother to explicitly set `window.OldLibrary`.

At first I tried using [script-loader](https://github.com/webpack/script-loader), but this wraps the script inside `function(module, exports) {}`, which means that `OldLibrary` now belongs to the scope of that function instead of `window`'s and this causes an exception. I also tried using imports loader like `imports?this=>window`, but this only sets `this` to `window`, so it doesn't have effect on functions that are supposed to be global.

Finally, I tried out `raw-loader`, but this just adds the script as a string, so it's not executed. Is there a way to tell Webpack to just concatenate the script as is without wrapping it inside another function?

**Edit**

It turns out that `script-loader` does actually handle this library as expected, I just wasn't matching it properly because it was the only file that didn't have a `.min.js` extension. I'm still interested in finding a way to concatenate scripts without wrapping them in functions, if possible.

Comment: _"Finally, I tried out `raw-loader`, but this just adds the script as a string, so it's not executed"_ Have not tried `webpack`, though you should be able to use `Function()` or `Blob()` to execute string as `javascript`.

Comment: @guest271314 interesting, do you know if there is a way to have webpack wrap the output from the `raw-loader` with a `Function()`?

Comment: Could you just put `let window;` at the top and `export window` at the bottom?

Comment: So long as the library doesn't refer to global methods and properties of `window` should be all good

Comment: `var script = "function OldLibrary() {
  console.log('What are modules?');
};var foo = window.OldLibrary;";
var fn = new Function("return " + script);fn()()` Though would not set `foo` to `window.OldLibrary`. Using `Blob()`, if possible, should return expected result.

Comment: @JayPea See [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) , [How to cache a downloaded javascript fle which is downloaded using script tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39784514/how-to-cache-a-downloaded-javascript-fle-which-is-downloaded-using-script-tag/)