# Http Call in IE is Slower then it should be

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, internet-explorer

I have been working on this angular site, where i send about a mb amount of data in a api call.

in Chrome and firefox, every thing works nice and fast. under a second. but in internet explore, it takes 18-20 seconds before getting the respons from the api, and takes about 30 seconds to render it out. I have been profiling to see if i could see something odd, and the only thing, that really look like is killing the site is the JS garbage collector in IE. Why I do not know,

[image]

If I log the time IE calls my api, and the timestamp the server send the response, it only takes a second. So what is it that IE can't handle? Anyone out there ever run into this before?

Comment: Could you show the view and controller? It won't be the time spent in the call itself but probably time spent while laying out the screen, with some adjustments to your view or controller should be possible to improve performance.

Comment: agreed. but its like IE just freez, waiting for the GC to clearn up space need for more action, where in Chrome and Firefox, it just rund.
we talking about 50 sekunds diff from IE to firefox/chrome. there may be something that can be improved in my code, but what I'm looking for, is why IE act this way. The request to see the view & controller, is not something i can grand, that i don't have the right to show it to anyone. Sry,

Comment: All I am saying is that I went through same process, thinking HTTP calls were to blame, and they weren't, IE was locking javascript to restyle and apply layouts which made calls to look slow. If you try to make the same calls without any change to the model, is it still slow?

Comment: It's not the HTTP calls. Its the way that IE works with the data, As i said, it's about 1 mb data, that need to be rendered on the siteIf i logged the time used on the server side, it takes no time, but in IE it takes forever, There for i blame the way IE handles this data, And when i use the profiler, it's always the GC that takes the time, there for i think is a memory problem. to answer your comment, Yes, i did, and it's not the HTTP calls that is to blame..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe cashing those files will help (so you don't have to load them over).
Here's cashing for JavaScript and PHP:
[caching JavaScript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311062/caching-javascript-files)

Comment: The system is slowed down by dom manipulation angular makes, of the site, The script and content is cached, so that won't help.